Change activity while application is running in background and automatically open the application to show the activity
For a project, I have implemented something similar to a step counter on an Android smartwatch. The goal now is to automatically display some kind of celebration activity (window, pop up...) if a specified count has been reached. The Activity should pop up on the watch face while the watch is running in the background. Basically, the same as many smart watches already have when you reach a daily goal.
I already tried with different kinds of Notifications which do appear in the notifications log on the watch but don't pop up on the watch face.
Kotlin Code:
private fun createNotification(title: String, text: String): Notification {
        val notificationIntent = Intent(this, ThresholdAchieved::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
        val channel =
            NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java).createNotificationChannel(channel)


        return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.splash_icon)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build()
    }


And then I call the function using:
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID_2, createNotification("TestNotification","This is a test notification"))

I also tried all the different Categories like CALL or ALARM etc. The required permissions were also added in the Manifest-file.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_SPECIAL_USE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />


I also checked in the watch settings that all the notification permissions were enabled.
I am happy for every Input I can get, thanks!
